# Firebase not able retrieve name for a specific google account

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the following code:

```
      var name = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        name: name,
        ip: ip,
        token: token
      });
```

to save user data into my database. I'm using a variety of accounts to test data flow and all seems good except for one particular account in which I am getting an empty value for the name (pulled by firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName).
Is there a reason this would be happening? Is it an issue with that particular account?

Comment: You're the only one of us who can check if the problematic account actually has a display name. But it seems likely that it doesn't.

Comment: Good point, it's hard to know without having direct access to the account. The weird thing is that I do in fact have a display name associated with the account. Could it possibly be because of some privacy setting on that account? I suppose this is more of a google problem than a firebase problem.